# How to Update and Insert Array of Objects in table with OPENJSON and where conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, where-clause, sql-insert, open-json

I want to update and insert the stock, InvM, and Invoice table with `OPENJSON()`. I am new at `OPENJSON()` in SQL Server. I have an array of objects and I want to insert each object to new row of the tables.
I want to iterate through every object and insert or update it using `Where` clause and `OPENJSON()`:

**Array of Objects:**

```
DECLARE @f NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[{
"Batch": "CP008",
"Bonus": -26,
"Code": 002,
"Cost": 50,
"Disc1": 0,
"Name": "Calpax_D Syp 120Ml",
"Price": undefined,
"Quantity": "1",
"SNO": 9,
"STP": 153,
"Stax": 0,
"TP": 50,
"Total": 50,
"invoiceno": 71,
"profit": 156,
"randomnumber": "3MO0FMDLUX0D9P1N7HGV",
"selected": false,
},
{
"Batch": "P009",
"Bonus": 0,
"Code": 823,
"Cost": 237.14999389648438,
"Disc1": 0,
"Name": "PENZOL TAB 40 MG",
"Price": undefined,
"Quantity": "2",
"SNO": 94,
"STP": 263.5,
"Stax": 0,
"TP": 263.5,
"Total": 527,
"invoiceno": 71,
"profit": 156,
"randomnumber": "3MO0FMDLUX0D9P1N7HGV",
"selected": false,
}
]'
```

How to update the Stock table and reduce the quantity with `where` condition if the Name of the medicine in the object array matches with the medicine in the Stock table (I came up with this but it is not working correctly):

```
UPDATE Stock 
SET Qty = Qty - qty  
from OPENJSON(@files) 
with(qty INT '$.Quantity', Name12 VARCHAR(55) '$.Name') 
where Stock.Name = Name12
```

Same goes for the InvM and Invoice table I want to insert new row with `where` condition

```
insert into InvM (RNDT, Dat, SMID, CID, Total, USR, RefNo, SRID, Txt,InvTime) 
 select RNDT, getdate(), Salesman.SMID, Customer.CID,@total, USR.Name, 0, 
 0,Salesman.Name,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 from Salesman, USR,Customer, OPENJSON(@files)  
 with(
    RNDT NVARCHAR(max) '$.randomnumber'
    )
 where USR.Name = 'moiz'



insert into Invoice (SNO, RNDT, Invno, Code, Name, Batch, STP, Qty, Bon, Disc, Stax, NET, 
TP, Cost, Profit)
select SNO, RNDT, InvNo, Code, Name, Batch, STP, Qty, Bon, Disc, Stax, NET, TP, 
Cost,profit  
from OPENJSON(@files) 
with (  
Batch INT '$.Batch',
Bon INT '$.Bouns',
Code INT '$.Code',
Cost INT '$.Cost',
Disc INT '$.Disc1',
Name NVARCHAR(Max) '$.Name',
STP INT '$.STP',
Qty INT '$.Quantity',
SNO INT '$.SNO',
Stax INT '$.Stax',
RNDT NVARCHAR(max) '$.randomnumber',
InvNo INT '$.invoiceno',
TP INT '$.TP',
NET INT '$.Total',
profit INT '$.profit'
)
```

Comment: The input is not a valid JSON, so `OPENJSON()` will return an error.

Comment: @Zhorov can you show me the correct way to update and insert with OPENJSON and where clause

Comment: Step 1 would be having valid JSON, @SyedMuhammadMoiz . Until then, you *can't* parse it as JSON, because it *isn't* (valid) JSON.

Comment: it is valid now @Larnu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the input JSON with `OPENJSON()` and update the table using an appropriate `JOIN`. The following example is a posiible solution to your problem:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Stock
FROM (VALUES
   ('PENZOL TAB 40 MG', 100),
   ('Calpax_D Syp 120Ml', 100)
) v (Name, Quantity)
```

JSON:

```
DECLARE @files NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
   {
      "Batch":"CP008",
      "Bonus":-26,
      "Code":2,
      "Cost":50,
      "Disc1":0,
      "Name":"Calpax_D Syp 120Ml",
      "Price":"undefined",
      "Quantity":"1",
      "SNO":9,
      "STP":153,
      "Stax":0,
      "TP":50,
      "Total":50,
      "invoiceno":71,
      "profit":156,
      "randomnumber":"3MO0FMDLUX0D9P1N7HGV",
      "selected":false
   },
   {
      "Batch":"P009",
      "Bonus":0,
      "Code":823,
      "Cost":237.14999389648438,
      "Disc1":0,
      "Name":"PENZOL TAB 40 MG",
      "Price":"undefined",
      "Quantity":"2",
      "SNO":94,
      "STP":263.5,
      "Stax":0,
      "TP":263.5,
      "Total":527,
      "invoiceno":71,
      "profit":156,
      "randomnumber":"3MO0FMDLUX0D9P1N7HGV",
      "selected":false
   }
]';
```

UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.Quantity = s.Quantity - j.Quantity
FROM Stock s
JOIN OPENJSON(@files) WITH (
   Name varchar(100) '$.Name', 
   Quantity int '$.Quantity' 
) j ON s.Name = j.Name
```

Result:

| Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| PENZOL TAB 40 MG | 98 |
| Calpax_D Syp 120Ml | 99 |

Comment: Thanks this helped alot can u also tell me how to use where clause properly in insert and OPENJSON

Comment: insert into Invoice (SNO, RNDT, Invno, Code, ...)
select SNO, RNDT, InvNo, Code, ....  
from OPENJSON(@files) 
with (  
Batch INT '$.Batch',
Code INT '$.Code',
.......
)where Stock.Code = Code;

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMoiz, the `INSERT` statement is correct, I'm probably missing something about the `WHERE` clause. Can you update the question with additional explanations? Thanks.